# ST_Tesselate on PolyhedralSurface is invalid : Polygon 0 is invalid: points don't lie in the same plane (and Is_Planar() only applies to polygons)

Tags: postgis, postgresql, sfcgal, tesselation, polyhedralsurface

Using [PostgreSQL 15](https://www.postgresql.org/)/[PostGIS 3.4.0](https://postgis.net/), I am having troubles when tessellating some polyhedral surfaces. Indeed, I have a table where 99% of the surfaces are giving correct tessellation results, but few of them are throwing an error (see hereunder).

One of these 'badly formatted' features is like this:

```sql
SELECT
  ST_Tesselate(
    ST_GeomFromText(
      'POLYHEDRALSURFACE Z (((
      29 58 58,
      29 58 62,
      31 51 62,
      31 51 20,
      28 59 20,
      28 59 58,
      29 58 58)))'
    )
  );
```

This returns:

```
NOTICE:  During tesselate(A) :
NOTICE:    with A: POLYHEDRALSURFACE(((29/1 58/1 58/1,29/1 58/1 62/1,31/1 51/1 62/1,31/1 51/1 20/1,28/1 59/1 20/1,28/1 59/1 58/1,29/1 58/1 58/1)))

ERROR:  PolyhedralSurface is invalid : Polygon 0 is invalid: points don't lie in the same plane : POLYHEDRALSURFACE(((29/1 58/1 58/1,29/1 58/1 62/1,31/1 51/1 62/1,31/1 51/1 20/1,28/1 59/1 20/1,28/1 59/1 58/1,29/1 58/1 58/1)))
SQL state: XX000
```

I think the message is clear and the feature is certainly missing some points, but for the moment I'm wondering if there are simple validity checks (and potential fixes) that I can perform prior to using the tessellation in order to avoid this blocking error?
Unfortunately, `ST_IsValid` is not working on 3D surfaces:

```sql
ERROR:  Unknown geometry type: 13 - PolyhedralSurface
SQL state: XX000
```

As suggested by user30184 in the comments below, I gave [`IS_Planar`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_IsPlanar.html) a try, without luck:

```
SELECT
  ST_IsPlanar(
    ST_GeomFromText(
      'POLYHEDRALSURFACE Z (((
      29 58 58,
      29 58 62,
      31 51 62,
      31 51 20,
      28 59 20,
      28 59 58,
      29 58 58)))'
    )
  );

ERROR:  is_planar() only applies to polygons
```

And this is not only because the geometry is not correct, it also returns the same error on a simple triangle:

```sql
SELECT
  ST_IsPlanar(
    ST_GeomFromText(
      'POLYHEDRALSURFACE Z (((
      0 0 0,
      1 0 0,
      1 1 0,
      0 0 0)))'
    )
  );

ERROR:  is_planar() only applies to polygons
```

Maybe it's bug because the doc actually states that:

> This function supports Polyhedral surfaces.

---

Versioning:

```sql
POSTGIS="3.4.0dev 3.3.0rc2-335-gae95dd219" [EXTENSION]
  PGSQL="150"
  GEOS="3.12.0dev-CAPI-1.18.0"
  SFCGAL="1.3.10"
  PROJ="9.2.0"
  LIBXML="2.9.10"
  LIBJSON="0.15"
  LIBPROTOBUF="1.3.3"
  WAGYU="0.5.0 (Internal)"
  TOPOLOGY
```

Answer (score 2):

I would have a try with ST_IsPlanar https://postgis.net/docs/ST_IsPlanar.html.

Comment: Good idea. I tried it but no luck: `ERROR:  is_planar() only applies to polygons
SQL state: XX000` which is strange because the documentation says: "This function supports Polyhedral surfaces." :-/

Answer (score 2):

Based on user30184's answer and because [`Is_Planar`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_IsPlanar.html) apparently only applies to polygons, I came up with the following workaround using [`ST_Dump`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Dump.html):

```sql
SELECT
  ST_IsPlanar(geom(ST_Dump(
    ST_GeomFromText(
      'POLYHEDRALSURFACE Z (((
      29 58 58,
      29 58 62,
      31 51 62,
      31 51 20,
      28 59 20,
      28 59 58,
      29 58 58)))'
    )
  )));
 st_isplanar 
-------------
 f
(1 row)
```

Or in the case of a square in the (x,y) plane:

```sql
SELECT
  ST_IsPlanar(geom(ST_Dump(
    ST_GeomFromText(
      'POLYHEDRALSURFACE Z (((
      0 0 0,
      1 0 0,
      1 1 0,
      0 1 0,
      0 0 0)))'
    )
  )));
 st_isplanar 
-------------
 t
(1 row)
```

With a polyhedral surface composed of more than one polygon:

```sql
SELECT
  ST_IsPlanar(geom(ST_Dump(
    ST_GeomFromText(
      'POLYHEDRALSURFACE Z (
        ((
          0 0 0,
          1 0 0,
          1 1 0,
          0 1 0,
          0 0 0)),
        ((
          0 0 0,
          0 1 0,
          0 1 1,
          18 0 1,
          0 0 0
        ))
      )'
    )
  )));
 st_isplanar 
-------------
 t
 f
(2 rows)
```

Now I have to figure out how to fix this geometry, which may be tricky...