# Why is this polygon not planar for PostGIS

Tags: postgis, postgresql, floating-point, sfcgal, cgal

Why is the following Polygon Z not planar for [PostGIS 3.4.0dev](https://registry.hub.docker.com/r/postgis/postgis/) (3.3.0rc2-335-gae95dd219)?

```sql
SELECT ST_IsPlanar(
  ST_GeomFromText(
    'POLYGON Z ((
      3021241.9043000005 2037823.3759000003 262.31250000034925,
      3021241.9043000005 2037823.3759000003 259.19920000003185,
      3021244.7461000010 2037817.7619999982 259.19920000003185,
      3021244.7461000010 2037817.7619999982 220.79300000029616,
      3021241.3140088190 2037824.5420044642 220.79300000029616,
      3021241.3140088190 2037824.5420044642 262.31250000034925,
      3021241.9043000005 2037823.3759000003 262.31250000034925
    ))'
  )
);
 st_isplanar 
-------------
 f
(1 row)
```

I made it planar with [`numpy`](https://numpy.org/) (1.23.4). But it seems that [PostGIS](https://postgis.net/) is more (how much? and what to do to fix it?) sensitive to numerical precision than `numpy` is.
My final residual with `numpy` was `5.684341886080802e-14`; and I cannot do much more with it.

Also, if before my computations, I divide the two first columns by 1e6 in order to keep them in the same range than the last column, it suddenly becomes valid (!):

```sql
SELECT ST_IsPlanar(
  ST_GeomFromText(
    'POLYGON Z ((
      302.12419043000006 203.78233759000003 262.31250000034925,
      302.12419043000006 203.78233759000003 259.19920000003185,
      302.12447461000010 203.78177619999983 259.19920000003185,
      302.12447461000010 203.78177619999983 220.79300000029616,
      302.12413140088190 203.78245420044640 220.79300000029616,
      302.12413140088190 203.78245420044640 262.31250000034925,
      302.12419043000006 203.78233759000003 262.31250000034925
    ))'
  )
);
 st_isplanar 
-------------
 t
(1 row)
```

But if I divide them prior to the computations, do the computations, and multiply them back by the same amount (1e6) after the computation in order to retrieve my original coordinates, it then becomes non-planar again.

Please also note that, in this specific case, it is a vertical plane (there are two points with different z at the same (x,y) position).

---

##### Addendum

As DavidP noticed in the comments bellow, "PostGIS is a 2.5D system" so I should work with polygons having same (x,y) for two different Z-values and that's right. What I'm actually trying to see, is if a real 3D feature having more than 3 3D points defining its boundary is planar. Initially this feature was `POLYHEDRALSURFACE Z`, based on the PostGIS SFCGAL backend. But unfortunately, `ST_IsPlanar` doesn't apply to polyhedralsurfaces:

```sql
SELECT ST_IsPlanar(
  ST_GeomFromText(
    'POLYHEDRALSURFACE Z (((
      3021241.9043000005 2037823.3759000003 262.31250000034925,
      3021241.9043000005 2037823.3759000003 259.19920000003185,
      3021244.7461000010 2037817.7619999982 259.19920000003185,
      3021244.7461000010 2037817.7619999982 220.79300000029616,
      3021241.3140088190 2037824.5420044642 220.79300000029616,
      3021241.3140088190 2037824.5420044642 262.31250000034925,
      3021241.9043000005 2037823.3759000003 262.31250000034925
    )))'
  )
);
ERROR:  is_planar() only applies to polygons
```

That's why I'm tweaking it to a Polygon Z feature; I can now make use of `ST_IsPlanar`. This tweak can be done by dumping the polygon out of the polyhedron using `ST_IsPlanar(geom(ST_Dump(ST_GeomFromText('...'))));` as described here: [ST_Tesselate on PolyhedralSurface is invalid : Polygon 0 is invalid: points don't lie in the same plane (and Is_Planar() only applies to polygons)](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/447297/65370)

I'm also obliged to tweak it this way because what is stated in the [`ST_IsPlanar`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_IsPlanar.html) documentation:

> - This method needs SFCGAL backend.
> - This function supports 3d and will not drop the z-index.
> - This function supports Polyhedral surfaces.
> - This function supports Triangles and Triangulated Irregular Network Surfaces (TIN).

is actually *not working* for my polyhedron! When directly applied to a polyhedron, it returns:

```sql
ERROR:  is_planar() only applies to polygons
SQL state: XX000
```

---

#### EDIT

Last but not least (?) I tried using [`np.longdouble`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.scalars.html#numpy.longdouble) when processing the data along with [`wkt.dumps()`](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html#well-known-formats) instead of the [`.wkt`](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/geometry.html#formatting) method which seems to [round values](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/94856/wkt-precision-rounding-using-shapely), but still not luck:

```
SELECT ST_IsPlanar(
  ST_GeomFromText(
    'POLYGON Z ((
      3021241.9043000005185604 1120823.3759000003337860 262.3125000003492460,
      3021241.9043000005185604 1120823.3759000003337860 259.1992000000318512,
      3021244.7461000010371208 1120817.7619999982416630 259.1992000000318512,
      3021244.7461000010371208 1120817.7619999982416630 220.7930000002961606,
      3021241.3140088189393282 1120824.5420044639613479 220.7930000002961606,
      3021241.3140088189393282 1120824.5420044639613479 262.3125000003492460,
      3021241.9043000005185604 1120823.3759000003337860 262.3125000003492460
    ))'
  )
);  
   
 st_isplanar 
-------------
 f
(1 row)
```

In this last experiment, the precision with `numpy` reached `3.469446951953614e-18`.

I also noticed that by manually changing these two '2' to '5's, the result becomes True:

[image]

I give up for the moment, it becomes non-sense...

My bet on a PostGIS bug maybe?

---

Versioning:

```
PostgreSQL 15.1 (Debian 15.1-1.pgdg110+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu,
compiled by gcc (Debian 10.2.1-6) 10.2.1 20210110, 64-bit

POSTGIS="3.4.0dev 3.3.0rc2-335-gae95dd219"
  [EXTENSION]
    PGSQL="150"
    GEOS="3.12.0dev-CAPI-1.18.0"
    SFCGAL="1.3.10"
    PROJ="9.2.0"
    IBXML="2.9.10"
    LIBJSON="0.15"
    LIBPROTOBUF="1.3.3"
    WAGYU="0.5.0 (Internal)"
    TOPOLOGY
```

Doc:

- [ST_IsPlanar](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_IsPlanar.html)

Comment: when I test your first snippet, I get TRUE.  Postgis 3.3.1, PG 14.2, Win 10

Comment: I was curious so I tested on a PG14.1/PostGIS 3.1.4 database, but I still get `False`. This is really weird...

Comment: It's probably those pesky floating point numbers.  You could try `st_isplanar(st_snaptogrid(geom,0.0000000001))`

Comment: something to do with how the chips in your hardware are processing floats, or yeah, maybe it's a bug.  If you haven't read about floating point numbers you should check it out

Comment: Maybe there is some sort of float error, but what strikes me at first glance is your "strange" geoms.  PostGIS is a 2.5D system, so I think geoms should be valid in the ground plane first (no repeated points with the same x,y). With simple gis features (like polygon z), you are not supposed to stack points on each other in the same geom. This can lead to strange behavior... IMHO...

Comment: Now I realize that st_isplanar is based on SFCGAL extension... then 2.5D should not be an issue...

Comment: Yes indeed, I added some background on this in my addendum. But shortly, on the one hand the [`ST_IsPlanar`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_IsPlanar.html) doc says: "This function supports Polyhedral surfaces." but on the other hand, when you try it on such polyhedralsurface it returns: `ERROR:  is_planar() only applies to polygons`. :-/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Short answer

PostGIS has to be build against SFCGAL >= 1.4 in order for the mentioned  polygon to be planar.

### Detailed answer

The mentioned polygon is not planar because `postgis_sfcgal` version (`1.3.10`) is not the most recent one in the PostGIS docker image, even the latest one.

There was an [issue](https://gitlab.com/Oslandia/SFCGAL/-/issues/247) with SFCGAL 1.3.x which has been fixed in versions >= 1.4.

But it is actually planar when PostGIS is compiled against SFCGAL 1.4.x:

```sql
SELECT ST_IsPlanar(
  ST_GeomFromText(
    'POLYGON Z ((
      3021241.9043000005 2037823.3759000003 262.31250000034925,
      3021241.9043000005 2037823.3759000003 259.19920000003185,
      3021244.7461000010 2037817.7619999982 259.19920000003185,
      3021244.7461000010 2037817.7619999982 220.79300000029616,
      3021241.3140088190 2037824.5420044642 220.79300000029616,
      3021241.3140088190 2037824.5420044642 262.31250000034925,
      3021241.9043000005 2037823.3759000003 262.31250000034925
    ))'
  )
);
 st_isplanar 
-------------
 t
(1 row)
```

I also tested it on a native Ubuntu 22.04 and it is also planar because the  `postgis` apt package is apparently build against SFCGAL version `1.4.1`:

```sql
-- On Ubuntu 22.04:
POSTGIS="3.3.2 4975da8"
  [EXTENSION] 
    PGSQL="150"
    GEOS="3.10.2-CAPI-1.16.0"
    SFCGAL="SFCGAL 1.4.1, CGAL 5.3.1, BOOST 1.74.0"
    PROJ="8.2.1"
    LIBXML="2.9.13"
    LIBJSON="0.15"
    LIBPROTOBUF="1.3.3"
    WAGYU="0.5.0 (Internal)"
    TOPOLOGY
```

As well as the PostGIS version of jbalk for sure.

On the other hand, the PostGIS Docker image is currently building SFCGAL from Oslandia sources and it is stuck in version 1.3.x because it relies on the [CGAL](https://www.cgal.org/) development package [`libcgal-dev` 5.2](https://packages.debian.org/bullseye/devel/libcgal-dev) in Debian bullseye (which is the base Docker image of PostgreSQL from which the PostGIS one is build):

```sh
apt-cache policy libcgal-dev
libcgal-dev:
  Installed: 5.2-3
  Candidate: 5.2-3
  Version table:
     5.2-3 500
        500 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main amd64 Packages
```

And if you try to build SFCGAL >= 1.4, e.g. the latest [1.4.1](https://gitlab.com/Oslandia/SFCGAL/-/tree/v1.4.1) release, using `libcgal-dev` 5.2, you will definitely run into troubles:

```sh
HEAD is now at 2d6a1a89 fix C header.
+ mkdir cmake-build
+ cd cmake-build
+ cmake ..
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 10.2.1
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 10.2.1
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc - skipped
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Setting build type to 'Release' as none was specified.
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/usr/src/SFCGAL/cmake-build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:67 (find_package):
  Could not find a configuration file for package "CGAL" that is compatible
  with requested version "5.3".

  The following configuration files were considered but not accepted:

    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/CGAL/CGALConfig.cmake, version: 5.2
```

This is certainly the reason why people building the PostGIS Docker image fell back on the latest version of SFCGAL that could be built on `libcgal-dev` 5.2, which is 1.3.x.

But fortunately, by fetching [`libcgal-dev` 5.5](https://packages.debian.org/sid/devel/libcgal-dev) from Debian testing (sid), it then becomes possible to build SFCGAL release `1.4.1`!

This is a small [hack](https://github.com/postgis/docker-postgis/pull/336), but I hope it will either be fixed soon or directly integrated.

So now my current PostGIS full version string looks like:

```sql
POSTGIS="3.4.0dev 3.3.0rc2-390-gc2a0b2024"
  [EXTENSION]
    PGSQL="150"
    GEOS="3.12.0dev-CAPI-1.18.0"
    SFCGAL="SFCGAL 1.4.1, CGAL 5.5.1, BOOST 1.74.0"
    PROJ="9.2.0"
    LIBXML="2.9.10"
    LIBJSON="0.15"
    LIBPROTOBUF="1.3.3"
    WAGYU="0.5.0 (Internal)"
    TOPOLOGY
```